# Bower won't install for some reason?

Tags: node.js, installation, bower

I'm attempting to install bower onto my personal laptop after having gone through the process at work.

I have installed Node.js and NPM as per usual, however when I run the command:

```
npm install -g bower
```

However I am seeing the following in my:
[Node.js Command Promt Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnkrv.png)

Could somebody please explain what is going on?

Adam

Comment: it installed, just some warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't  worry about it. Bower already installed on your Window PC. Please check Bower installed or not by running the below command:

`bower -v`

If you do not see the semantic version of Bower at the first time ( something like `1.8.0`. Please close terminal and try it again

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hate it when things look different on every machine you use.